# How to establish layering in ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture

I am about to develop an MVC application in .NET and read through many articles. I am very confused about the layering of the application. One school of thought is about create separate project for each layer while others say create folders inside same project. I am struggling to understand the difference and pros and cons of following either approach. Could you please explain which option is better and why?

Comment: Can I just ask why are you asking this question? For academic reasons or some real world problem you are facing? This is also an opinionated question so don't be surprised if it gets flagged.

Comment: I am looking for real world solutions

Answer (score 0):

If you create separate project it will be very hard to understand,
Try to create different folder based on the category

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put your Views and Controllers in the same ASP.NET MVC project. For Models, that depends. Classes that are specific to your applications (that is useless to other applications) should also be put in your ASP.NET MVC application project. However, classes that could be useful to other applications, should be put in seperate projects.

Do not worry too much about where you put your model classes. You can always refactor them. This is normal software maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no right or wrong when it comes to this but there are pros and cons to the approaches.

### Multiple projects

To understand why people might want to do this you need to understand how apps where build on the desktop. Usually the desktop application was gigantic with many classis so people put everything in separate projects in order to have a better view of the code. This had the added benefit of not having to compile the whole code base on slow machines when you changed something. Second thing was you could share the code between multiple applications like the domain layer. Where your desktop app and the server app had some common layers. This is not common in modern web development and code sharing is not recommended between different app because a change in one might lead to a regression. Since a project will compile to a separate dll(if you don't configure something different) this might allow you to do a plugin system where you load the dll at runtime and not have any down time on the server but this requires modular architecture to pull off.
The benefit of this is that you can switch upper layers with out having to change the base layers in most cases UI.
Imagine you have the common traditional layers

- DataAccess
- BusinessLogic
- UI

You could in theory swap any the UI layer with out having to make any changes to the other two layers, and have the new UI project just reference the old projects, this might happen if for example you change from mvc to signalr or Nancy. Also you could swap out the data access layer with out having to change anything in the UI layer. If you keep everything in the same project this would be more difficult since your project could not get rid of the MVC dependence with out refactoring or copying the code from one project to the other.

### Single project

This is quite common for small codebases because it's simple and doesn't require any projects and you just do a new web site project and start implementing our logic. But if your app gets big the compiling will probably be slow but maybe not that noticeable on a modern fast machine.
this approach is common in microservices world where you don't want you project to have multiple dll's and want to keep things as small as possible. Because the layer swap will almost newer happen in an actual project you won't need to prepere for this.

Also it's difficult to make abstraction of stuff like a data access layer because nature of databases is different. Stuff that is supported on one is probably not supported on the other, I once had to do a change from NHibrenate to Entity Framework and you would be surprised what don't work on one that works on the other, I think people trying to change EF to EF core can testify to this as well. This will also create performance issues because it's almost impossible to maximize performance over an abstraction.

As I said this is mostly an opinion so there is no write or wrong. Something else that I can tell you is that I almost completely stopped recommending layered architecture and started using feature architecture. It makes much more sense for me and fits well with modern agile and/or scrum way of working in companies. [Check out Jimmy Bogard he has multiple talks about the subject](https://vimeo.com/131633177).